# AutoMapper Map to different type based on an enum?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm starting to implement [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), first I managed to integrate it with Castle.Windsor, which I'm already using. Now I have a `Post` entity which I want to map to either a `LinkPostModel` or an `ImagePostModel`. Both inherit from `PostModel`

**1)** This is what I have so far:

```
public class PostModelFromPostEntityConverter : ITypeConverter<Post, PostModel>
{
    private readonly IPostService postService;

    public PostModelFromPostEntityConverter(IPostService postService)
    {
        if (postService == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("postService");
        }
        this.postService = postService;
    }

    public PostModel Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        Post post = (Post)context.SourceValue;
        Link link = post.Link;
        if (link.Type == LinkType.Html)
        {
            return new LinkPostModel
            {
                Description = link.Description,
                PictureUrl = link.Picture,
                PostId = post.Id,
                PostSlug = postService.GetTitleSlug(post),
                Timestamp = post.Created,
                Title = link.Title,
                UserMessage = post.UserMessage,
                UserDisplayName = post.User.DisplayName
            };
        }
        else if (link.Type == LinkType.Image)
        {
            return new ImagePostModel
            {
                PictureUrl = link.Picture,
                PostId = post.Id,
                PostSlug = postService.GetTitleSlug(post),
                Timestamp = post.Created,
                UserMessage = post.UserMessage,
                UserDisplayName = post.User.DisplayName
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Obviously the point in implementing [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is removing repeat code like this, so how am I supposed to map the common stuff, before adding my custom rules (such as the if-clause)

Ideally I'd want this to be something like:

```
public class PostModelFromPostEntityConverter : ITypeConverter<Post, PostModel>
{
    [...]

    public PostModel Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        Post post = (Post)context.SourceValue;
        Link link = post.Link;
        if (link.Type == LinkType.Html)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<Post, LinkPostModel>(post);
            // and a few ForMember calls?
        }
        else if (link.Type == LinkType.Image)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<Post, ImagePostModel>(post);
            // and a few ForMember calls?
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**2)** After this mapping is complete. I have a "parent" mapping, where I need to map an `IEnumerable<Post>` the following model:

```
public class PostListModel : IHasOpenGraphMetadata
{
    public OpenGraphModel OpenGraph { get; set; } // og:model just describes the latest post
    public IList<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

So basically I'd need another `TypeConverter` *(right?)*, which allows me to map the posts list first, and then create the `og:model`

I have this, but it feels kind of clunky, I feel it could be better:

```
public class PostListModelFromPostEntityEnumerableConverter : ITypeConverter<IEnumerable<Post>, PostListModel>
{
    public PostListModel Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        IEnumerable<Post> posts = (IEnumerable<Post>)context.SourceValue;
        PostListModel result = new PostListModel
        {
            Posts = posts.Select(Mapper.Map<Post, PostModel>).ToList()
        };
        Post first = posts.FirstOrDefault();
        result.OpenGraph = Mapper.Map<Post, OpenGraphModel>(first);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**3)** I didn't actually run the code yet, so another question comes to mind, and that is why aren't mappings strongly typed in converters?

```
IEnumerable<Post> posts = (IEnumerable<Post>)context.SourceValue;
```

where it could actually be

```
IEnumerable<Post> posts = context.SourceValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get Necromancer badge.
Nowadays this task can be solved much easier with using `ConstructUsing` function specifc fields should be filled in the provided action, but all the common fields will go to `ForMember` execution of the mapping. Collections in this case doesn't requires any additional logic/mapping configurations. Classes that has a property of type collection as well.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Post, PostModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(p =>
    {
        switch (p.Type)
        {
            case LinkType.Html: return new LinkPostModel
            {
                Title = p.Description
                // other specific fields
            };
            case LinkType.Image: return new ImagePostModel
            {
                // other specific fields
            };
        }
        return null;
    })
    .ForMember(x => x.PostId, m => m.MapFrom(p => p.Id));
cfg.CreateMap<PostList, PostListModel>();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46610884/20977501) worked.

It uses Automapper's ConstructUsing to return context.Mapper.Map statements based on the predicate.
*Leaving this here in-case this is the first search result like it was for me*