# No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, nullable, coercion

I am using AutoMapper for object mapping. Sometime the source value is null so i want to substitute it with "" rather than putting NULL in database.
The source object have many nullable data types like Date, Decimal and Int.
Currently i am using

```
public class Invoice 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }        
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }        
        public InvoiceType Type { get; set; }
        public InvoiceStatus Status { get; set; }
        public LineAmountType LineAmountTypes { get; set; }     
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }        
        public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }        
        public DateTime? ExpectedPaymentDate { get; set; }        
        public DateTime? PlannedPaymentDate { get; set; }        
        public decimal? SubTotal { get; set; }        
        public decimal? TotalTax { get; set; }        
        public decimal? Total { get; set; }        
        public decimal? TotalDiscount { get; set; 
        public decimal? CurrencyRate { get; set; }        
        public DateTime? FullyPaidOnDate { get; set; }        
        public decimal? AmountDue { get; set; }        
        public decimal? AmountPaid { get; set; }        
        public decimal? AmountCredited { get; set; }

    }

public partial class TempInvoice
    {
        public int RowId { get; set; }
        public System.Guid InvoiceID { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> ContactID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string LineAmountType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExpectedPaymentDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> PlannedPaymentDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SubTotal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TotalTax { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Total { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TotalDiscount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> CurrencyRate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FullyPaidOnDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AmountDue { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AmountCredited { get; set; }
    }


    public class InvoiceMapper : Profile
        {
            public InvoiceMapper()
            {
                CreateMap<Invoice, TempInvoice>()
                    .ForMember(des => des.PaymentID, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                    .ForMember(des => des.InvoiceID, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Invoice.Id))
                    .ForMember(des => des.PaymentDate, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Date))
                    .ForAllMembers(src => src.NullSubstitute(""))//this doesn't work
                    ;
            }
        }
```

But i am getting the above error.
Is there a way i can exclude the datatime type and set int or decimal to 0 and string to "" ? Is there a generic method i can use for all datatypes?
Thanks

Comment: Simple how can DateTime even take "", this is a string type so incompatible. `DateTime dt = ""` is incorrect usage

Comment: I am aware of that , is there a way i can exclude the datatime type and set int or decimal to 0 and string to ""

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35949590/1559611, you can use the option like:
`.ForMember(dest => (...), opt => { 
        opt.Condition(src => Null Condition);
        opt.MapFrom(src => Actual mapping);`

Best option is provide a separate null mapping for each type, instead of trying one for all

Comment: Do you think it is possible to post all of the data types represented here? (And I mean all of them).

Comment: @Mrinal i could do that but i was looking if there is a better way.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have posted all my data types.

Comment: @SumanPalikhe - I did ask for all of them. The code you post should be copy, paste, and compile so that it is as easy as possible for us to help. You should post the types for `Contact`, `InvoiceType`, `InvoiceStatus`, and `LineAmountType`, along with the signatures for `.CreateMap`, `.ForMember`, and `.ForAllMembers`. Or, alternatively, you could reduce down the code to just show the issue you're facing (which would mean only leaving the relevant properties). But in any case the code should be complete (and not just what you think is relevant).

Comment: You just can't call `ForAllMembers(src => src.NullSubstitute()` and expect it to work with different data types. Either specify it on each property, or set appropriate defaults in your database.

Comment: What version of AutoMapper are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a resolver function with ResolveUsing, using your own custom mapping function that returns an empty string if the destination is a string, otherwise null.

For example:

```
    private static object MyMapperResolver(object source, bool returnEmptyString = true) {
        return source ?? (returnEmptyString ? "" : source);
    }

    public static IMapper InitMappings() {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<Invoice, TempInvoice>()
                .ForMember(des => des.PaymentID, map => map.ResolveUsing(src => MyMapperResolver(src.Id)))
                .ForMember(des => des.InvoiceID, map => map.ResolveUsing(src => MyMapperResolver(src.Invoice.Id)))
                .ForMember(des => des.PaymentDate, map => map.ResolveUsing(src => MyMapperResolver(src.Date, false)))
                ;
        });
        return Mapper.Instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddTransform`

```
public class InvoiceMapper : Profile
{
    public InvoiceMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<Invoice, TempInvoice>()
            .ForMember(des => des.PaymentID, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(des => des.InvoiceID, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Invoice.Id))
            .ForMember(des => des.PaymentDate, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Date))
            .AddTransform<string>(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? "" : s); // this line
    }
}
```