# AutoMapper c# runtime mapping depending on an object property

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to know, how could I, with AutoMapper, Map one Dto to multiple entities.

Lemme explain.

I've got one Dto, with an enum to describe its type (to avoid having multiple dtos)

Depending on that enum (RelationType here), I would like to map it to the correct Model (Entity, what ever, it's another object that I use in database).

```
public class BCardDto : IMappedDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public BCardRelationType RelationType { get; set; }
    public long RelationId { get; set; }
}
```

Here are is my Model base:

```
public class BCardModel : IMappedDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

And here the derived model :

```
public class CardBCardModel : BCardModel
{
    // ormlite, ignore that
    [Reference]
    public CardModel Card { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(CardModel), ForeignKeyName = "fk_bcard_card")]
    public long RelationId { get; set; }
}
```

How do I map my Dto to the correct Model depending on the enum i've given ?
(I don't wanna use Mapper.Map everywhere but I wanna let mapper do the runtime mapping job)

Here is how I do it for the Model -> Dto

```
        cfg.CreateMap<CardBCardModel, BCardDto>()
            .ForMember(s => s.RelationType, expression => expression.UseValue(BCardRelationType.Card))
            .IncludeBase<BCardModel, BCardDto>();
```

Tell me if I do something wrong and explain me why please :)

Thanks by advance,
Blowa.

Comment: Looks like someone got the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526660/automapper-map-to-derived-objects-depend-on-condition) don't know if it's the right solution tho

Comment: So where is the other model that you want to map to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a setup wherein there is a base class and 2 classes which derive the base class:

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ModelOne : ModelBase { }

public class ModelTwo : ModelBase { }
```

Let's also say you have a DTO with an enum as below:

```
public class ModelDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ModelType ModelType { get; set; }
}

public enum ModelType
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

So now the task is: *How do I map the `ModelDto` to either `ModelOne` or `ModelTwo` depending on the value in `ModelDto.ModelType` property?*

Here is how:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ModelDto, ModelBase>().ConstructUsing(x => 
{
    switch (x.ModelType)
    {
        case ModelType.One:
            return new ModelOne { Name = x.Name };
        case ModelType.Two:
            return new ModelTwo { Name = x.Name };
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown ModelType...");
    }
}));
```

**Usage**

```
var dto1 = new ModelDto { ModelType = ModelType.One, Name = "ModelOne" };
var dto2 = new ModelDto { ModelType = ModelType.Two, Name = "ModelTwo" };

var one = Mapper.Map<ModelBase>(dto1);
var two = Mapper.Map<ModelBase>(dto2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I wanted to do :) !
But I think that I will use AutoMapper instead of return new (i know that you used it for example)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the mapping is by using dynamic:

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDto : PersonDto
{
    public int studentNumber { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeDto  : PersonDto
{
    public string EmployeId { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public int StudentNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Employe : Person
{
    public string EmployeId { get; set; }
}
```

Create Map by using:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<StudentDto, Student>();
Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeDto, Employe>();
```

Do the Mapping by:

```
try
{
    var student = MapPerson((dynamic) studentDto);
    var employe = MapPerson((dynamic) employeDto);
}
catch
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown ModelType...");
}
```

And define two Methods

```
public static Student MapPerson(StudentDto studentDto)
{
    return Mapper.Map<StudentDto, Student>(studentDto);
}

public static Employe MapPerson(EmployeDto employeDto)
{
    return Mapper.Map<EmployeDto, Employe>(employeDto);
}
```

The benefit is that you don't need a key and avoid the switch statement